# Will cd/bin/cat command work on Linux operating system?

Tags: linux

Will `cd/bin/cat` command work on Linux operating system? It's not working, but why?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why isn't it working? What exactly are you doing?

Comment: Please add to your question: exactly the command you typed, and the precise message you got in response. "It's not working" is useless information: if it worked, you would not be posting the question.

Comment: Edit the question to tell us what you are trying to do. Not just the command (you have that), what are you expecting it to do?

Answer (score 5):

Running `cd/bin/cat` in the shell would work if the current directory contains a directory called `cd`, which in turn contains directory `bin` and that has an executable `cat`. Otherwise you'd probably get errors like "No such file or directory".

On the other hand `cd /bin/cat` would try to change the current directory to `/bin/cat`, which probably doesn't work, since that's usually the location of the [standard utility `cat`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/cat.html), and binary files for programs are *files*, not directories. It's not impossible for it to be a directory, though, but that would be a somewhat strange system.

Answer (score 1):

There are two reasons that I see.

You need a space after the command. You have to separate the command from it parameters. (So MS-Windows dose not need a space, but that just makes it more prone to doing un-expected thinks.)
`cd /bin/cat`

The next problem is that `/bin/cat` is not a directory (well almost certainly not).

I can not tell you more, as I know not what you are trying to do.